# UITableView IBOutlet crash on ViewDidLoad for Apple Beta Review Team not for me

Tags: ios, swift, crash

My app keeps being rejected by Apple Beta Review Team because of what they claim is a crash at boot. Point is the crash never happens on any simulator or device on my side.

The symbolicated crash log reports something like the following, but the line 74 reported in HomeViewController.swift (here I report an image of the code submitted to the Beta Review Team)

[image]

is simply referencing a UITableView IBOutlet coming from the storyboard, if I put a breakpoint here the tableView is instantiated. I am using swift, iOS 9.3.2 and Xcode 7.3.1.

EDIT: Line 87 is same, calling a function  renderButton(btnOpened, selected: true) on a UIButton IBOutlet.

I tried setting zombies, address sanitizer, I keep not having the crash, they keep having it, I have no clue what possibly could fix this. Does anyone has any idea of what could be wrong?

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Sportito                      0x00000001000cee40 HomeViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (HomeViewController.swift:74)
1   Sportito                      0x00000001000ce990 HomeViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (HomeViewController.swift:87)
2   Sportito                      0x00000001000cee60 @objc HomeViewController.viewDidLoad() -> () (HomeViewController.swift:0)
3   UIKit                         0x0000000186934c40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
4   UIKit                         0x0000000186934844 -[UIViewController view] + 28
5   UIKit                         0x0000000186cdaaec -[UINavigationController preferredContentSize] + 172
6   UIKit                         0x0000000186b9adf4 -[UIViewController(UIPopoverController_Internal) _resolvedPreferredContentSize] + 68
7   UIKit                         0x0000000186b9a858 -[UIPopoverController _transitionFromViewController:toViewController:animated:] + 152
8   UIKit                         0x0000000186b9a48c -[UIPopoverController _initWithContentViewController:popoverControllerStyle:] + 836
9   UIKit                         0x0000000186f5ac7c -[UISplitViewController _setupHiddenPopoverControllerWithViewController:] + 120
10  UIKit                         0x0000000186f5aeec -[UISplitViewController _viewControllerHiding:] + 356
11  UIKit                         0x0000000186f62b60 -[UISplitViewController viewWillAppear:] + 208
12  UIKit                         0x000000018694d374 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
13  UIKit                         0x000000018694d0e8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
14  UIKit                         0x000000018693cf14 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 596
15  UIKit                         0x000000018693c13c -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 444
16  UIKit                         0x000000018693b7e8 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 664
17  UIKit                         0x0000000186938a88 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 252
18  UIKit                         0x00000001869aefa4 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48
19  UIKit                         0x0000000186bda3ac -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3456
20  UIKit                         0x0000000186bde5f0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
21  UIKit                         0x0000000186bdb764 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
22  FrontBoardServices            0x000000018317f7ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
23  FrontBoardServices            0x000000018317f618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
24  FrontBoardServices            0x000000018317f9c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
25  CoreFoundation                0x000000018179509c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
26  CoreFoundation                0x0000000181794b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
27  CoreFoundation                0x0000000181792830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
28  CoreFoundation                0x00000001816bcc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
29  UIKit                         0x00000001869a394c -[UIApplication _run] + 460
30  UIKit                         0x000000018699e088 UIApplicationMain + 204
31  Sportito                      0x000000010002e860 main (AppDelegate.swift:42)
32  libdyld.dylib                 0x000000018125a8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Is the app set as universal? Could they be getting the crash on an iPad while you're testing on an iPhone, or vice-versa?

Comment: Line 87 is same, calling a function  renderButton(btnOpened, selected: true) on a UIButton IBOutlet.

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi You've probably tried installing the beta onto one of your devices, and it doesn't crash for you then either?

Comment: @dzk yes, on more than one device, and it doesn't crash. Also it doesn't crash on any simulator, even after resetting them.

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi I'm talking about the actual beta binary that you submitted for review, you can install the package through TestFlight before the app has been accepted in review. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding you now.

Comment: Can you bring some more light to the line 87? And if any function is being called over there, please post that code as well.

Comment: @dzk, I believe I understood you, I have installed the binary through TestFlight either on my device, and on other real devices, you meant this right?

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi Yes, exactly. This is a curious mystery.

Comment: @FabrizioProsperi By the way, is HomeViewController a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?

Comment: It is UIViewController, and in any case I also have delegate and datasource set on the XIB itself. Those lines could also be removed, which I did in another build I submitted to the Beta Review Team and waiting for outcome. But I believe the issue is in the XIB objects not been instantiated correctly. I now tried to move that in viewDidAppear (even if viewDidLoad is perfectly fine usually). I don't understand why they are having a crash when I am not!

Comment: @DannyBravo, that is true, app is marked Universal and is not ready for iPad yet, I will try to submit an archive for iPhone only and see if that is the issue, in that case you should put your comment as an answer and I will mark that as the solution, hopefully! THANKS, finger crossed.

Comment: @Fabrizio Prosperi: Hopefully that will fix this. I've posted my comment as an answer per your recommendation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the app set as universal? Could they be getting the crash on an iPad while you're testing on an iPhone, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

According to apple's guideline your app must not crash on iphone or ipad whether your app is universal or not.

If your app is iPhone only then it should run in small resolution on ipad but it must not crash in any situation, because from appstore user can download iphone only app from ipad also so, it shouldn't crash.

So, check in iPad also that your app is not crashing.

If your app is universal then there shouldn't problem of resolution in ipad or iphone both.

So, make sure which mistake you are doing.

hope this will help :)

Comment: This answer was also correct, but @Danny said that in a comment previously. Thanks.